# Switching GWT.create(XXX.class) by Custom Annotation

Tags: gwt, binding, annotations

I hope that you're all coding well. So... I was refactoring the client side of the GWT app I work on and I was wondering about something. Looking after an answer days after days, I decided to ask you for your point of view...

The title is quite understanding, but, there is a snippet of what I'd like to do.

I'd like to change stuff like this

```
public AnnotatedObject annotated = GWT.create(AnnotatedObject.class);
```

by something like this

```
@CreativeAnnotation
public AnnotatedObject;
```

I had to say that in my xxx.gwt.xml, I have done something like this :

```
<replace-with class="package.AnnotationObject2">
    <when-type-is class="package.AnnotationObject" />
</replace-with>
```

As you can see, my deffered replacement class is AnnotationObject2, and for the moment, I add a line between the ones above and I have :

```
<replace-with class="package.AnnotationObject1">
    <when-type-is class="package.AnnotationObject" />
    <when-property-is name="type" value="object1" />
</replace-with>

<replace-with class="package.AnnotationObject2">
    <when-type-is class="package.AnnotationObject" />
    <when-property-is name="type" value="object2" />
</replace-with>
```

I don't really like to play with metadata of my xxx.html, so the result I'd like is this one :

```
@CreativeAnnotation(type = "object2")
public AnnotatedObject;
```

So, do you think that sort of thing is possible with GWT (I have to say that I work with GWT 2.5, 'cause of my client desires) ? If yes, may you help me ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : I mean, I know about GIN... Just wondering how to do it from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using dependency injection with GIN.
GIN automatically use GWT.create() to create an object that has to be injected.
Ex:

```
class MyView  {
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyView> {
    }

    @Inject
    MyView(MyUiBinder uiBinder) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

And with dependency injection, you also specify which implementation of your interface to instantiate in your GIN module:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractGinModule {
 protected void configure() {
   bind(AnnotationObject.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("object1").to(AnnotationObject1.class);
   bind(AnnotationObject.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("object2").to(AnnotationObject2.class);
 }
}
```

And then in your code:

```
public class MyClass {

  @Inject
  public MyClass(@Named("object1") AnnotationObject annotationObject) {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can also use custom binding annotation instead of the Named annotation.

Comment: +1, as I was about to give a similar (probably less detailed) answer! Gin is exactly the solution to the given problem. We use it in our GWT application and nearly never use GWT.create()...

Comment: Thanks Julien for your answers. In fact, I was applying your best practices, and I used GIN before. Just wondering if it was possible to write a GIN-like quickly. But in reality, your proposition is the best thing to do and more when it's a "company-do-it-quickly-or-we-will-find-someone-else" context. Fortunately, it's not and it was just for my personal ambition.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own generator if you don't want to use GIN - for something like this it would be pretty trivial.